# Why do I get only a half of html source code?

Tags: android, html, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

In my android app I use a asynctask to get a html source code from a website.
For that I use HttpURLConnection like that:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://xx.com/test.pl");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String temp;
        while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&sid=(.*?)\"");
            //Matcher match = pattern.matcher(temp);

            System.out.println(temp);

            Log.e("temp_HoleKunde", temp);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exe) {
        exe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I always used this when I parse a Website and it always runs fantastic.
But now I have a very serious problem. The source code, which I log on logcat, isn't the full source. Only half of it is showing.. or more and sometimes less.
How can I get the full source code like on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs aren't meant to print out thousands of lines of code. I'm sure that it will display the whole source code once you set it to a `TextView`.

Comment: @StefanM.  It is very useful, when you don't try to use it for a purpose for which it was never designed.  Have you considered the design impacts if logcat accepted an arbitrarily large amount of text?  Logcat is not for displaying output.